# Modify URL Before Loading Request in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, url, cookies, uiwebview

I created a native app from my web app using `UIWebView`.

My webapp is a basic CMS with some static pages, some category pages and and some detail pages.

Now I need to check if the request comes from the web app or the native app.

To do this I have two possibilities:

First solution: Modify URL and check URL on server side:

```
@IBOutlet var WebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadWebPage()
}

func loadWebPage() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888?apptype=native")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!) 
    WebView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

When I check on server side if the the parameter exists on the first page it works, but when I switch to other pages (categories etc.) the condition fails.

Second solution: I tried to set cookies:

```
@IBOutlet var WebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadWebPage()
}

func loadWebPage() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    var cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as! [NSHTTPCookie]

    var reqCookies:[AnyObject] = []

    for aCookie in cookies {

        reqCookies += [aCookie]

    }

    var headers = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(reqCookies)

    WebView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

But how do I add cookies in this example in the response so I can retrieve them on server side?

Are there any other solutions or how can I modify my existing ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` method [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:).

When the user taps a link in the webview, this delegate method is called.  Take the `request.url` of `NSURLRequest` passed into the delegate method and create a new `NSURLRequest` with `?apptype=native` appended to the `request.url` property.

Comment: lI tried this solution, but it did not work for me. How did you guys do it?