# How to add a parameter to all urls in uiwebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

How can I add a parameter to all url detected in uiwebview? I want to append all the url string with this parameter: ?app=1.

Right now I only use 1 UIWebViewDelegate:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
}
```

Is there another delegate I can use to achieve this?

What I have tried:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let url = (request.URL?.absoluteString)! + "?app=1"
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: url)
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    //Load url into WebView container
    //webView.loadRequest(req)


    return true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - UIWebView Modify url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253997/swift-uiwebview-modify-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is sufficient to have that done when the link is actually selected by the user , consider altering it in your web view's delegate's

```
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

and taking apropriate action, such as returning false and manually load the modified url.

Edit in response to edited question:

try something along these lines (no IDE handy atm):

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

if let url = request.URL {
   if url.absoluteString.rangeOfString("?app=1") != nil {
      // everything is fine. 
      return true
      }
   else {
     let newRequest = // build new request here
     webView.loadRequest(newRequest)
     return false
     }
 }


return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your quick answer @JanGreve, but what should I implement in this delegate to add the parameter to the uiwebview's url?

Comment: the method's argument gives you the generated request, which includes the NSURL that has been selected. I'd examine it for having the appropriate get parameter and if yes, let it pass, otherwise, create a new NSURL by appending the parameter, then sending the new url to the web view for loading, blocking the original request by returning false.

Comment: [Take](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) [a](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLRequest/URL) [look](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc%28cs%29NSURL).

Comment: See my edited question. That is what I have tried, but it does not work.

Comment: I did update my answer with a rough sketch in code, @LocDaiLe. does that help? Also, might work your way through the not-exactly-duplicate-but-close link provided by JAL.